# Hashicorp's Vault Certiticate Authentication not working. How to configure server and client certificates?

Tags: vault, hashicorp

I am trying to enable TLS authentication in a Vault that is deployed within a Kubernetes cluster. My goal is to be able to login to the vault using cert method as follows:

```sh
vault login \
    -method=cert \
    -ca-cert=vault-ca.pem \
    -client-cert=cert.pem \
    -client-key=key.pem \
    name=web
```

I first deployed the vault following this [page](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/helm/examples/standalone-tls) against a minikube cluster. This page creates the vault server's public key, private key and certificate. With these three files, I assume any connection to the server will be secure. The steps I followed were as follows:

## Creating a standalone TLS vault server

### 1.  Create env variables

```sh
# SERVICE is the name of the Vault service in Kubernetes.
# It does not have to match the actual running service, though it may help for consistency.
SERVICE=vault-server-tls

# NAMESPACE where the Vault service is running.
NAMESPACE=vault-namespace

# SECRET_NAME to create in the Kubernetes secrets store.
SECRET_NAME=vault-server-tls

# TMPDIR is a temporary working directory.
TMPDIR=/tmp
```

### 2. Create a private key for the vault server

```sh
openssl genrsa -out ${TMPDIR}/vault.key 2048
```

### 3. Create and deploy Certificate Signing Request

- 3.1) Create a file `csr.conf`

```sh
$ cat <<EOF >${TMPDIR}/csr.conf
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = ${SERVICE}
DNS.2 = ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}
DNS.3 = ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc
DNS.4 = ${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
EOF
```

- 3.2) Create the Certificate Signing request using the configuration in `csr.conf`

```sh
openssl req -new -key ${TMPDIR}/vault.key -subj "/CN=${SERVICE}.${NAMESPACE}.svc" -out ${TMPDIR}/server.csr -config ${TMPDIR}/csr.conf
```

- 3.3) Put the Certificate Signing Request in a CertificateSigningRequest yaml for Kubernetes

```sh
$ export CSR_NAME=vault-csr
$ cat <<EOF >${TMPDIR}/csr.yaml
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: ${CSR_NAME}
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: $(cat ${TMPDIR}/server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
EOF
```

and apply it in Kubernetes

```sh
kubectl create -f ${TMPDIR}/csr.yaml
```

- 3.4) Approve the Certificate Signing Request

```sh
kubectl certificate approve ${CSR_NAME}
```

### 4. Get the Vault server's Certificate

```sh
serverCert=$(kubectl get csr ${CSR_NAME} -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}')
```

and put it in a file

```sh
echo "${serverCert}" | openssl base64 -d -A -out ${TMPDIR}/vault.crt
```

### 5. Get Certificate Authority's certificate

```sh
kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten -o jsonpath='{.clusters[].cluster.certificate-authority-data}' | base64 -d > ${TMPDIR}/vault.ca
```

At this stage, I have the vault server's private key `vault.key`, its certificate `vault.crt` and the CA certificate `vault.ca`

### 6. I can put these files into a Kubernetes secret to be used by the vault server deployment.

```sh
kubectl create secret generic ${SECRET_NAME} \
     --namespace ${NAMESPACE} \
     --from-file=vault.key=${TMPDIR}/vault.key \
     --from-file=vault.crt=${TMPDIR}/vault.crt \
     --from-file=vault.ca=${TMPDIR}/vault.ca
```

### 7. Finally deploy the vault server with a Helm chart and the following custom values

```yaml
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: false

server:
  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.ca

  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: vault-server-tls # Matches the ${SECRET_NAME} from above

  standalone:
    enabled: true
    config: |
      listener "tcp" {
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.crt"
        tls_key_file  = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.key"
        tls_client_ca_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.ca"
      }

      storage "file" {
        path = "/vault/data"
      }
```

```sh
$ helm repo add hashicorp https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com
$ helm install vault hashicorp/vault --values values.yml
```

## Authenticate with Cert

I `kubectl exec` into the pod `vault-0` and I init and unseal the vault.

Then I try to login using the files I created. I know that they are the same as the server's files. However, since they are paired and signed, I would expecte them to work. Also, I did go into the Vault's UI and added vault.ca as the certificate to be used in TLS Acess.

```sh
$ vault login -method=cert -ca-cert=/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.ca -client-cert=/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.cr
t -client-key=/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/vault.key
```

However, I get this error:

```sh
Error authenticating: Error making API request.

URL: PUT https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/cert/login
Code: 500. Errors:

* failed to verify client's certificate: x509: certificate specifies an incompatible key usage
```

My TLS understanding is limited. Could anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: iirc kubernetes already limit the TLS Usage for non kuberentes component, you should generate the tls outside of the kuberentes itself..